# Uploading a Directory using ftp4j

Tags: java, ftp, ftp4j

I am trying to write a recursive function which will upload a directory entirely onto the ftp server. I need to check if the directory I am uploading is already there so I require to check if the dir exist. But in ftp4j I am not able to find any such functions as of now.

Code:

```
if(!upclient.isConnected()){
    upclient.connect(ftp_ip);
    upclient.login(ftp_login, ftp_pass);
}
//i want to check here if the dir exit..if no i will create one
upclient.changeDirectory(ftpupload_path);
if (upclient.isConnected()) {
    System.out.println("Connected to " + ftp_ip);
    File local_dir=new File(local_path);
    File[] uploadFiles=local_dir.listFiles();
    for (File uploadfile : uploadFiles) {
        if(uploadfile.isFile()){
            System.out.println("Uploading" + upclient.currentDirectory() + "/" + uploadfile.getName());
    upclient.upload(uploadfile);
        } else if(uploadfile.isDirectory()){
            uploadDir(ftp_ip, ftp_login, ftp_pass,upclient.currentDirectory()+"/"+uploadfile.getName(), uploadfile.getAbsolutePath());
            upclient.changeDirectory(ftpupload_path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the directory exists and if not create it, you can use this code:

```
try {
    upclient.changeDirectory(dir);
} catch(FTPException e) {
    upclient.createDirectory(dir);
    upclient.changeDirectory(dir);
}
```